# UILabel: adding 1 to a number when button pressed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, numbers, uilabel

I am fairly new to this, I would really like some help on how to change a UILabel to add 1 to the previous number, everytime a the button is pressed. I.E i want it so when I press the button the UILabel turns from 0 to 1, and if I press it again it turns from 1 to 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced. I know that I would have to create the button, but I don't know the code to put in their?

Comment: you should get familiar with the basics of iOS development. you can find tons of tutorials in google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
//header 
@property (nonatomic) int i;
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
//implementation
- (void)viewWillAppear{
self.i = 0;
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
self.i++;
[self.textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.i]];
}
```

`self.textField` is whatever text area you want to display the number in. Also, you have to make the connection from the `buttonClicked` action to the button in interface builder, if you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

`label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [label.text intValue] + 1];`

Answer (score 0):

Set your Label to '0' in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
[lblMoves setText:@"0"];
```

Change Counter on Button Click & Update Label

```
- (IBAction)incrementLabel:(id)sender
{
    int cnt = [[lblMoves text] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Current %d, Next %d",cnt, ++cnt);
    [lblMoves setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cnt]];
}
```